# How to add all files to stage whose file path is given in a file

Tags: git, git-add

Let's say I have a file `files_to_stage.txt` having file paths like

```
src/a/a1.txt
src/a/a2.txt
src/b/b3.txt
src/b/b6.txt
src/c/c5.txt
```

Now I want to stage all files having paths present in `files_to_stage.txt` for instance `src/a/a1.txt, src/a/a2.txt` etc.

How can I do it? I am looking for something like

```
git add -f files_to_stage.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git add $(cat files_to_stage.txt)
```

should be enough.

The subcommand (the `$()` construct) reads out your file and sends it to `git add`.

Comment: Amazing.. Thanks :) Can't demand anything more. Sometimes we get so much obsessed with command flags that we forget wonders of shell :) Thanks for reminding me of that.